Help with uxto frm 2009 wallet
So somehow,I transferred all my old bitcoin to a newer native segwet address.In which I cant find the pk...Is there somthing im missing..Now I see a uxto for the entire amount. Please Help!Thank u so much.

Hey Mark, could you provide more details? Which software did you use? How did you generate the wallet that you sent to? What were you trying to do that led you to believe that you cannot find the public key?

To be completely honest.I was working with,third web,zerion,kraken,and bitstamp at the time..I thought I was signing a nft contract on my ens..My impatient ADHd Ways.lol.When on third web. I THINK I somehow accidentally signed the big bitcoin..I checked the input wallet and sure enough i have it saved in my files from way back..

I have signed and verified..What do I do now?

It was a huge transaction,,It made world news....1000 BTC!!!!

Hi Mark, please take a step back and think about what a potential answerer would have learned from your post and comments so far. What do you need help with? What do people need to know in order to help you with it?

What would you do.If you accidentally sent your 998.

Bitcoin to a address in which you cant find the pk?
